# How to make conditional calculations in a table using loop mechanisms?

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have the following table ('ABC'):

[image]

---

Goal: For each date, create 2 new variables (e.g. 'LSum' and 'USum'). 'LSum' should calculate the sum of all cell values across the column universe (4-281), but only with those values whose header is in the cell array of ABC.L, for that specific date. In the same fashion, 'USum' should calculate the sum of all cell values across the columns, but only with those values whose header is in the cell array of ABC.U, for that specific date.

---

```
% load content
load ('ABC.mat'); 
% run through every date, starting from the top 
for row=1:size(ABC,1); 
% for-loop for 'L' that determines for what specific cells (of col. 4-281) the following calculation has to be done: how? 
% for-loop for 'U' that determines for what specific cells (of col. 4-281) the following calculation has to be done: how? 
% now generate new variables
LSum = sum(); % But how can I use if clause here to select only eligible cells that enter into the sum calculation? 
USum = sum(); % Same problem here as LSum
end; 

% Concatenate table ABC and the newly formed variables into 1 table
ABC = [ABC(:,1:3) LSum USum ABC(:,3+1:end)];
```

---

Thanks for your help, especially for the looping through date and the cell arrays of 'L' and 'U' at the same time.

---

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you already tried, and explain any difficulties you ran into.

Comment: %load content: `load ('ABC.mat');` %run through every date, starting from the top: `for row=1:size(ABC,1);` %for-loop for 'L' that determines for what specific cells (of col. 4-281) the following calculation has to be done: how? %for-loop for 'U' that determines for what specific objects in col. 4-281 the following calculation has to be done: how? %Now generate new variables: `LSum = sum();` %But how can I use if clause to select only eligible cells? `USum = sum(); end; end; end;` %Concatenate table ABC and the newly formed variables into 1 table: `ABC = [ABC(:,1:3) LSum USum ABC(:,3+1:end)];`

Comment: Please edit the question and add this code inside.

Comment: Done! please see above section, Dev-iL. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible way how to avoid loops is to utilize rowfun() function. Suppose we have table similar to yours.
[image]

Augment the table by column with table variable names.

```
tb = horzcat(tb,repmat({tb.Properties.VariableNames},1,height(tb))');
```

Define function which is applied onto every row.

```
function out = selectiveSum(varargin)
  [~,~,sumColsId] = intersect(varargin{2},varargin{end});
  out = sum(cell2mat(varargin(sumColsId)));
end
```

Run rowfun().

```
sums = rowfun(@selectiveSum,tb);
```

The function deals just with one selector array (L column). Add the second one and let the selectiveSum() return 1x2 vector.

Comment: Thank you Maple Mapleson! When applying the _out function_ the following error message occurred: "Function definitions are not permitted in this context." Do you know how to mitigate this issue?

Comment: It's selectiveSum() function, _out_ is just output. If you have older than 2016b version of Matlab you have to define the function in separate file.

Comment: No, I am using the 2016b version. The error message still occurs. `function out = selectiveSum(varargin)
 ↑
Error: Function definitions are not permitted in this context.`

Comment: Ok, anyway did you try to save the selectiveSum() function into separate file selectiveSum.m and then call sums = rowfun(@selectiveSum,tb); ? Function definition provided above has valid syntax.

Comment: I have saved it separately. Nonetheless it doesn't work: I attached the error message above now so you can see. thanks for looking into it again

Comment: Did you augment your table ABC as tb = horzcat(tb,repmat({tb.Properties.VariableNames},1,height(tb))'); ? It seems like the varargin{end} argument is not cell array. Make sure the last column in your table consists of cell arrays.